# opencv user drawing rectangle to crop

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get a user to be able to draw a rectangle around an object and crop it-

with this code--

```
def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):

global refPt, drawing, cropping

if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    drawing = True
    refPt = [(x, y)]
    cropping = True

elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    if drawing == True:
        cv2.rectangle(closeres, refPt[0], (x,y),(0,255,0),2)


elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    drawing = False
    refPt.append((x, y))
    cropping = False

    cv2.rectangle(closeres, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("image", closeres)
```

it draws multiple rectangles not just one that changes size, it ends up looking like this-

[image]

anyone know how to fix this so it changes size instead?
if I change code to this-

```
elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
    if drawing == True:
        closeres = cloneclone
        cv2.rectangle(closeres, refPt[0], (x,y),(0,255,0),2)
```

to try to erase the rectangle each time it changes i end up seeing nothing , no rectangle and get this message-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project2.py", line 38, in click_and_crop
    cv2.rectangle(closeres, refPt[0], refPt[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e54pa.jpg), (0, 255, 0), 2)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'closeres' referenced before assignment

Comment: clone the original image before drawing. draw to the clone and display the clone but keep the orihinal image.

Comment: yeah I am doing that already unless i am misunderstanding what you are saying that doesn't help the green rectangle resizing issue

Comment: Sorry, Im not familiar to the python syntax. where is the image copied/cloned? must be done before each rectangle drawing. and you must display the clone.

Answer (score 2):

You have to draw the image each time at the start of your event hanling routine instead of inside the last if condition.
THEN draw the sizer rectangle. Otherwise the previous rectangle is not deleted. Image is progressively destroyed.
The higher the refresh rate, the greener your image becomes.

A possible optimization is to use a XOR mode so if you draw previous rectangle again it restores the image (but rectangle cannot be plain green in that case) but it is more complex

Comment: Im confused what you mean by that, wouldnt I have to severely alter my code in order to do that? I tried adding this so it erase rectangle each time but it didnt work-

Comment: elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            closeres = image.copy()
            cv2.rectangle(closeres, refPt[0], (x,y),(0,255,0),2)

Comment: you mean like do imshow of the image I am drawing before the if statements but still in the crop and cut method?

Comment: Exactly. There will be exactly one rectangle, not a rectangle trail like in your post